# Changing the browser language settings show a different name on the collumns

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, language, edge

So basically, i have a SPO site that runs across multiple countries.

The users use the change language settings on the browser, to have the language settings changed on the site.

The site language is by default in English.
I have a user that was working on a list on the site, while he had the browser settings in german, and he changed the names on the collumns, but then when other people have different languages the list is not displaying the changed names.

It shouldn't be a translation error as the fields were changed from Released to Ger. and Working to Eng.
We tried Edge and Chrome

As seen in the picture independently of the language, the field is always the original, could have something to do with this? any one have an idea?

[image]

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Column display names can have translations for each language. When your user was viewing the SharePoint site in German, he changed the German translation of the column name but the column name translations for the other languages have not been changed. Users viewing the site in other langauges therefore noticed no difference.

With regards to the field URL parameter, this is the internal column (field) name which is immutable and does not have translations.

Answer (score 0):

As Callum Crowley mentioned, the field name in the URL is the internal column name, which doesn't vary by language.

The lack of translation for other users is probably caused by caching caused by Project Nucleus.  Column names of lists are stored locally on the browser in a SQL Lite table on your hard drive, courtesy of OneDrive sync.  It is eventually flushed.  You can check the localized column name by going to the list settings screen while in the other language.